# How to add naked domain (without www) on GoDaddy deployed via Heroku?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, heroku, cname

I have a domain that's been deployed via Heroku, and is up and running fine with the www. But if I go to the domain without the www, it does not render correctly. I tried adding both domains on Heroku, with www and without www, but unfortunately it still does not work.

Also, I tried following step two on here ( http://documentation.unbounce.com/hc/en-us/articles/203687274-Setting-Up-Your-CNAME-with-GoDaddy-godaddy-com- ) but continued to get an error: `An unexpected error occurred. If this issue continues, contact support.`

How can I add a naked domain to GoDaddy to forward to my web deployed on Heroku like my domain with www?

Thank you

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding another A record, with the same IP but using `@` instead of `www` for the host name.

Also remember that changes take an average of half an hour to make effect.

Comment: I have two A records at the moment. Which IP should I add? Please look at the original post with the image update. Also just wondering how is that going to cover for the naked domain?

Comment: You should add the IP of your Heroku instance for both records. The `@` subdomain covers for the naked domain.

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify on Heroku instance for both records? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Edit then replace with your hosting IP

and save it

Comment: sorry but to the heroku IP? Is that GoDaddy dashboard?

Comment: yes this is godday dashboard. you need to fined your heroku IP and replace with godaddy IP

Answer (score 0):

[image]try to set TXT and CNAM as well[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image: i had same issue with azure application where naked domain couldnt be reach]

Comment: sorry but to which URL address?

Comment: im not sure via Heroku 
but in my case I had an application hosted in microsoft azure with same problem.
so this is how I figure it up.

Comment: no worries but is the pic of the dashboard GoDaddy?

Comment: no its not GoDaddy. but i used GoDaddy with same functionality.